# Does bootstrap_features parameter is useful if I use max_features parameter in RandomSearch optimizing Bagging

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I understand why I can use max_samples and bootstrap at the same time. For example I may have 'n' samples and whether bootstrap is used or not will change prediction of single estimator and whole ensemble. But in case of features should it has some sense? Or it depense on estimator? Becouse I see no sense if estimator is tree.

```
#BaggingRegressor
bagging_regressor = BaggingRegressor(oob_score=False, warm_start=False)
bagging_regressor_params = {
    'n_estimators'       : list(range(10, 3000, 50)),
    'max_samples'        : np.arange(1e-2, 1+1e-2, 1e-2),
    'max_features'       : np.arange(1e-2, 1+1e-2, 1e-2),
    'bootstrap'          : [True, False],
    'bootstrap_features' : [True, False],
    'base_estimator'     : [DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion=criterion, 
                            splitter=splitter, max_depth=max_depth) \
                            for criterion in ['mse', 'friedman_mse', 'mae'] \
                            for splitter in ['best', 'random'] \
                            for max_depth in range(1,10)
                            ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with `bootstrap_features`; there is probably a reason it is set to `False` by default. I could not find any literature or documentation explaining why this would be useful. So, please take this answer with a grain of salt. It is not based on authoritative literature but on my own thoughts.

#### What is feature bootstrapping?

For training an individual model in an ensemble, a subset of features is selected randomly. Bootstrapping means the features are selected with replacement. This means that the model could get duplicates of the same feature.

#### What could go wrong?

- Some models are allergic to duplicate features. For example `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` emits a warning that *Variables are collinear.*
- Some models do not care. For example, CART trees select the best feature for a split, so it does not matter if a feature occurs twice.

#### Why could feature bootstrapping be useful?

- Some decision trees select features randomly. Having a duplicate feature increases the chance of this feature being selected.
- Reduce Bias, increase variance. The purpose of ensemble methods such as Bagging is to average a number of low bias / high variance models. Duplicate features could, in principle, increase the variance of a model by increasing the number of fitted coefficients in the model.
- Increase variability between models. Sampling a fixed number features without replacement results in fewer possible feature combinations than sampling the same number of features with replacement. (e.g. There are 5 combinations to select 4 out of 5 features without replacement. But there are 70 combinations to select 4 out of 5 with replacement).

Personally, I do not think above reasons are very useful. You can usually control variability and model overfitting by bootstrapping samples rather than features. I would leave `bootstrap_features=False` unless you have very strong reasons (literature, theoretical considerations) to use it.